# MobileFirst push notification- poll not works

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I try to run the next simple code example on my mobilefirst 6.3 studio, and it doesn't works. It do nothing.
What am I missing?

```
 WL.Server.createEventSource({
    name: 'PushEventSource1',
    poll: {
        interval: 3,
        onPoll: "test1"
    }
 });
 function test1() { 
    WL.Logger.info(new Date() + ": test!");
 }
```

I deploy it successfully:

```
[2015-02-09 10:23:02]             Starting adapter deployment on MobileFirst Server 
[2015-02-09 10:23:02]             Starting build of adapter: PushAdapter 
[2015-02-09 10:23:02]             Deploying adapter: PushAdapter 
[2015-02-09 10:23:02]             Server host: 10.0.0.177 
[2015-02-09 10:23:02]             Server port: 10080 
[2015-02-09 10:23:03]             Adapter build and deploy finished.
```

Comment: When you say 'doesn't work', I assume you mean that the polling function is not called? Are you sure you have deployed the adapter successfully? How are you deploying it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "not working" you mean that you do not see the log line in the server log, then make sure that in Eclipse, in the Servers view > Server Configuration > Logging section, the "Console log info" option is set to `INFO`.